# django-admin.py can't find custom settings file

Tags: django, django-admin, django-settings, django-manage.py

I have several customized django settings, this is basically my project structure:

```
MainProject/
  manage.py
  my_project/
    settings/
      base.py
      dev.py
      prod.py
```

I've created the `__init__.py` files inside the directories to identify them as packages.
I've exported the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to point to the chosen settings file.
The `manage.py` command seems to handle it pretty good, I never had problem with it.

The **problem** is that no matter what I do the `django-admin.py` is **not able to find any settings** file. I've tried several possible solution but nothing seems to work so far.

1. I've used the `--settings=my_project.settings.dev`
2. I've edited and hard-coded the `manage.py` to let it point to the dev.py file
3. I've created a `settings` file either inside the `MainProject` and `my_project` directories importing the *dev* file (that in turn imports the base.py).
4. I've created a `settings` file that let Django know which files should it use as `settings`

This is regarding the point 4:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
try:
    import my_project.settings.dev as settings
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("Couldn't find the settings.py module.")
    sys.exit(1)
setup_environ(settings)
```

Nothing seems to work so far.

====================================

**SOLUTION:**
I did not find the exact solution but thanks to a comment on the chosen answer I understood that you can basically use `manage.py` for everything that you could do in `django-admin.py`, I didn't know that! Since things DO work for me using `manage.py` I'm fine with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I recommend doing:

Create a normal settings.py file and import one of the others in there. This avoids duplication of settings shared among the three scenarios + it is actually the recommended way of doing it according to the DRY principle.

Typically, you will only have the set the debug parameter, database settings and private keys in the specific settings files. All the other settings should be shared among all scenarios to avoid forgetting to update one and getting hard to debug errors.

Comment: Done that. It works for manage.py, it doesn't for django-admin.py

Comment: You're not supposed to use django-admin.py, ou should use manage.py. It takes care of setting up the environment and can execute all commands django-admin can. [See the Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/)

Comment: Didn't know that! It works for me with manage.py so I solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Yes, `$ python manage.py check --deploy --settings=my_project.settings.production` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import the dev settings inside the `__init__.py` from your settings module?

**settings/_*init*_.py**

`from .dev import *`